# React-Native INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE:Package com.schoolproject signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring

Tags: react-native, installation, release-mode, debug-mode

Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException:
> INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.schoolproject signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!

Solution of that type error

U will get that type error if you are run on your mobile using npx react-native run-android

1. please uninstall app-release.apk app if you already installed it on your device.

1.1 why required to uninstall- because the same name two application unable to install
one application is release mode and one is on debug mode same name app.

2. then after run command npx react-native run-android

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You might just have a same application in your device already, uninstall it and then run the app again.

Such error comes when your signature of the old version and new version does not match.
Read more here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

If you want to have multiple apps based on different types, then add productFlavours in your application.
Read more on that [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants).

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method boolean com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.ReaLayoutAnimator.isLayoutAnimationEnabled() ona null object reference    .. I getting that types error I have already fixed some files as MainApplication.java and build.gradle  but unable to resolve that error